# Customizar Lista dentro do painel Admin - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

estou em um projeto, que preciso fazer algumas alterações exatamente dentro do painel do Wordpress. Mais especificamente em uma página que lista uma lista especifica de post.

- Eu preciso adicionar um campo de busca customizado com um campo especifico.
- Preciso também na mesma tabela adicionar mais algumas colunas.

Verifiquei a [documentação do wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table). Porém é algo muito superficial, não muito explicativo.

Alguém já precisou fazer?.

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou procurar algum plugin que faça o que você deseja?

Comment: Sua descrição está muito genérica. Coloque um print da tela que quer modificar e explique o que vai onde. Se possível com algum código que vc já tenha tentado e qual erro teve, dai fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Se vc acha a documentação do WP superficial, sinto dizer que vc vai se surpreender negativamente com algumas coisas que vai encontrar por aí.

Comment: Se não for isto, deve ser parecido: [Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/578/12615)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja nesse exemplo tirado do codex, como você pode adicionar / manipular colunas :

```
/* Display custom column */
function display_posts_stickiness( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ($column == 'sticky'){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" disabled', ( is_sticky( $post_id ) ? ' checked' : ''), '/>';
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'display_posts_stickiness', 10, 2 );

/* Add custom column to post list */
function add_sticky_column( $columns ) {
    return array_merge( $columns, 
        array( 'sticky' => __( 'Sticky', 'your_text_domain' ) ) );
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'add_sticky_column' );
```

Referência : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

Quanto ao campo de busca personalizado, qual tipo de informação você gostaria de filtrar / buscar ?

De qualquer forma veja no link abaixo alguns exemplos de filtros possíveis :
https://www.sitepoint.com/customized-wordpress-administration-filters/

Comment: Era isso mesmo que precisava. Links bem explicados e detalhados. Obrigado .. +1 /\